# Traefik cluster mode on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

The Traefik documentation is unclear when running Traefik on Kubernetes.

I want multiple instances of traefik running in my cluster, sharing one configuration and the acme file.

The configuration is initially provided with a `ConfigMap`.
Now the documentation states that one needs a separate KV-store to achieve traefik clustering.

But is that not covered by Traefik running Kubernetes mode?

Answer (score 1):

Briefly what  you have to do is the following:

- deploy a key value store (either inside or outside kubernetes) by choosing one of the supported (consul, etcd, zookeeper, boltdb)
- Run the traefik storeconfig command once by passing a configuration file in order to copy your configuration into the kv store
- Run traefik with the proper flags to load configuration from the kv store.

Everything Is explained here https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kv-config/

This is not a kubernetes specific guide, but it is quite simple to adapt it.

Comment: FWIW, a proposal to support Let's Encrypt more natively in Kubernetes has been published very recently: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2542